# MATLAB: image AlphaData changes figure size

Tags: image, matlab, size, border, figure

I have two images: `im2` needs to be overlayed over `im1` with a constant alpha map of 0.5. Whenever I set the `'AlphaData'` for `im2` (to reveal `im1` below), the size of the figure/axes changes slightly. If my axes occupies the whole figure, some border pixels go missing. The following example demonstrates this problem by two example images, where `im2` has a yellow border so you can clearly notice this problem:

```
close all;

frame_sz = [106 777];
% create a white im1
im1 = ones([frame_sz 3]);

% create im2 with a yellow border
im2 = zeros([frame_sz 3]);
im2(:,1,[1 2]) = 1;
im2(:,end,[1 2]) = 1;
im2(1,:,[1 2]) = 1;
im2(end,:,[1 2]) = 1;

% create the figure at a specific location with size equal to image
screen_sz = get(0,'ScreenSize');
fg_h = figure('units', 'pixels', 'position', ...
    [screen_sz([3 4])-frame_sz([2 1])-40 frame_sz([2 1])], ...
    'paperpositionmode', 'auto');
ax_h = axes('Parent',fg_h);

% show first image
imshow(im1, 'Parent',ax_h, 'InitialMagnification','fit');
hold on;
% display im2 ontop of im1
h = image(im2, 'Parent',ax_h);
% set the axis such that image occupies the whole figure
set(ax_h, 'Units','normalized', ...
    'position', [0 0 1 1], 'visible', 'off');
axis off;

%%%%%%%%%%%% PROBLEM HAPPENS HERE %%%%%%%%%%%%%
% as soon as I set the AlphaData couple of pixels 
%  go missing from the right and bottom side
set(h, 'AlphaData', ones(frame_sz([1 2]))*0.5);
```

The problem occurs regardless of if I am overlaying using image() or just simply using image() to display an image. As soon as I set the AlphaData, the sizing of the axes slightly changes and chops off some borders.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What happens if you set `'AlphaData'` to a scalar .5? What happens if you use `imshow` for `im2` as well? Why are you toying with the axes `ax_h`? Why don't you use `'Border'='fit'` property of `imshow`?

Comment: Oh thanks for the pointer - I am now using a scalar 0.5 directly as 'AlphaData', but this doesn't solve the problem. I have tried imshow and 'Border' as 'tight' and 'loose' - nothing works. All give the exact same result.